# Trouble using a custom image for splitViewController displayModeButtonItem (UIBarButtonItem) Swift IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a splitViewController to enable a slide out menu in my app, using Swift on iOS 9.

I have everything working as desired except that I cannot get a custom image for my "Menu" button (which is the splitViewController's displayModeButtonItem).

Here is what I have tried.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

  // This will create a properly-working menu barbuttonitem, but is of course
  // a text based title.

  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "≡", 
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
    target: splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().target,
    action: splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().action)
```

This version is my attempt to use a custom image instead of a text title, but I just get a gray box where the image should be.

```
  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "29x29"), 
    style: .Plain, 
    target: splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().target, 
    action: splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().action)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make a `UIButton` and set the image in it and set that as a leftBarButtonItem like so in your `-viewDidLoad`:

```
let menuButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29)
menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"29x29"), forState: .Normal)
menuButton.addTarget(self, action: "menuPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

and in a separate method, perform your action:

```
func menuPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    //show menu
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jasonnoahchoi, your solution solved my barbuttonitem image problem!  The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to continue leveraging the splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem() action and target.  While I know how to toggle the splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode, I can't seem to retain the animated show/hide of my Menu now...

Comment: Okay, I got it now.  To trigger the built-in  splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem() action I am calling:  UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().action, to: splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem().target, from: nil, forEvent: nil). Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice! Very glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: Any idea why this works for me on an iPad but not an iPhone?

Comment: The action of `displayModeButtonItem` is dependent on the result of `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:`. On iPad, this result changes. On iPhone, it is always `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`. To get it to work on iPhone, you need to check `self.splitViewController.isCollapsed` and if it is, you have to manually dismiss the detail view controller with `[self.navigationController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` (or NO, whatever you need ). If it's not, forward the action like @bayarea desicibes above.